# Django DateField default options

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have a model which has a date time field:

```py
date = models.DateField(_("Date"), default=datetime.now())
```

When I check the app in the built in django admin, the `DateField` also has the time appended to it, so that if you try to save it an error is returned. How do I make the default just the date? (`datetime.today()` isn't working either)

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Your mistake is using the `datetime` class instead of the `date` class.  You meant to do this:

```
from datetime import date
date = models.DateField(_("Date"), default=date.today)
```

If you only want to capture the current date the proper way to handle this is to use the `auto_now_add` parameter:

```
date = models.DateField(_("Date"), auto_now_add=True)
```

However, the [modelfield docs](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#datefield) clearly state that `auto_now_add` and `auto_now` will *always* use the current date and are not a default value that you can override.

Comment: Nice to know about `auto_now_add`. One thing to be aware of though is that it creates a read-only field, which is unfortunate, though it makes sense for `auto_now`.

Answer (score 172):

This is why you should **always import the base `datetime` module: `import datetime`**, rather than the `datetime` class within that module: `from datetime import datetime`.

The other mistake you have made is to actually call the function in the default, with the `()`. This means that all models will get the date *at the time the class is first defined* - so if your server stays up for days or weeks without restarting Apache, all elements will get same the initial date.

So the field should be:

```
import datetime
date = models.DateField(_("Date"), default=datetime.date.today)
```

Comment: Is there a way to do this adding a time delta?  For example: default=datetime.date.today + datetime.timedelta(days=4)   ... this code doesn't work, but that's the idea.  (Granted, the save method is one place to do this, but just wondering if there's a way to do this as part of the definition)

Comment: @Joe J: this should be a new question really. But the fact that you can use a callable means you can just define your own function that returns today+4.

Comment: What is `_("Date")` doing?

Comment: @benregn It's giving the field a label of "Date" but marking it for translation using the internationalization system.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying that, I've just started Django dev and it was a bit unclear to me if it was doing more that just labeling.

Comment: This causes problems when the date is displayed in the admin system: `Caught AttributeError while rendering: 'datetime.date' object has no attribute 'date'` any ideas why?

Comment: @benregn You'll need to include `from django.utils.translation import gettext as _` for internationalization

Comment: @jdero or in this particular situation you want to use the `lazy` version, so `from django.utils.translation import gettext_lazy as _` as otherwise evaluation at import time will spit a 'AppRegistryNotReady'

Comment: This functionality seems to be missing from `django.utils.timezone`, any workaround ideas?

Comment: I get `TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'default'`

Answer (score 7):

```
date = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now, blank=True)
```

Comment: DateTimeField is not the same. If you provide a datetime as default to a DateField, you'll have trouble.

Comment: 1) The question is about `DateField` and 2) using `datetime.now` (a naive timezone) instead of [`timezone.now`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/utils/#django.utils.timezone.now) may have unwanted consequences. So this answer is double-trouble.

Answer (score 6):

I think a better way to solve this would be to use the datetime callable:

```
from datetime import datetime

date = models.DateField(default=datetime.now)
```

Note that no parenthesis were used. If you used parenthesis you would invoke the `now()` function just once (when the model is created). Instead, you pass the callable as an argument, thus being invoked everytime an instance of the model is created.

Credit to [Django Musings](https://medium.com/django-musings/current-datetime-for-default-value-in-a-model-use-callables-85e092e68fa6). I've used it and works fine.

Answer (score 5):

### DateField/DateTimeField.auto_now_add

> Automatically set the field to now when the object is first created. Useful for creation of timestamps. Note that the current date is always used; it’s not just a default value that you can override. So even if you set a value for this field when creating the object, it will be ignored.
> **Source**: [Django
> doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.DateField.auto_now_add)

This should do the trick:

```
models.DateTimeField(_("Date"), auto_now_add = True)
```

Comment: my friend I think you read it wrong. Question is about DateField not about DateTimeField.

Comment: @xxbinxx but work fine with DateField :) https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.DateField.auto_now_add

Answer (score 4):

You could also use `lambda`. Useful if you're using [django.utils.timezone.now](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/utils/#django.utils.timezone.now)

```
date = models.DateField(_("Date"), default=lambda: now().date())
```

Comment: Look at [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/models/fields/#default). It is not good to use lambda as default callable wrapper:

`Note that lambdas cannot be used for field options like default because they cannot be serialized by migrations. See that documentation for other caveats.`

Comment: @pulina you're right, but in this case when you need date binded to configured timezone this looks like the only solution

Comment: Nope. You can point a actual function in code. Any function or method reference according to [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/migrations/#migration-serializing) in connection that is model top level function.

Answer (score 0):

**django hint**:

HINT: It seems you set a fixed date / time / datetime value as default for this field. This may not be what you want. If you want to have the current date as default, use `django.utils.timezone.now`

Answer (score 0):

I tried the below on Django version 4.1.7 and worked perfectly!

```py
from datetime import datetime, date

class Example(models.Model):
    purchase_date = models.DateField(auto_now_add=False, auto_now=False, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.str(purchase_date)}"
```

Returning this is entirely optional.
Working perfectly either you return the string or not.

Comment: This python is full of syntax errors and basic linter issues. I tried to correct some in my edit, but realized this may have been generated by AI or something. To name a few issues: unnecessary import, `__str__` causes infinite recursion, also passes arg to `self.str(...)` which doesn't take arguments. Perhaps most importantly, this _**does not** satisfy the original question_: how do you set a datetime default on a django model field?