# Django admin datefield-datetimefield confusion

Tags: django, datetime, date, django-admin

I have a model similar to given below, in django 1.1.2:

```
from datetime import datetime
...
class Blah(models.Model):
    ...
    date = models.DateField(default=datetime.today)
```

in admin interface, default value for date is given as datetime (yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss.ms)
on each new record. it complaints that the value does not match the field constaints if i forgot 
to correct the value by removing the hour part.

how can i fix it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you want a date, use `datetime.date.today` instead of `datetime.datetime.today`. Always import the `datetime` *module*, not the class, so you can tell which is which.

```
import datetime
...
class Blah(models.Model):
    ...
    date = models.DateField(default=datetime.date.today)
```

Comment: thanks, i forgot that datetime.today also returns a datetime object instead of date.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like this thread can help.

[Django DateField default options](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2029295/django-datefield-default-options)