# coercing form input data to uppercase

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

I'm getting attribute errors "'NoneType' object has no attribute 'strip'" when trying to coerce form input data to uppercase. My forms code (clean method borrowed from another programmer) is:

```
class PostPageForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta: 
        model = PostPage
    def clean(self):
        return dict([(k, v.strip().upper()) for k, v in self.cleaned_data.items()])
```

and my model:

```
class PostPage(models.Model):
    client = models.CharField(max_length=50, choices=CLIENT_CHOICES)
    job_number = models.CharField(max_length=30, unique=True, blank=False, null=False)
    job_name = models.CharField(max_length=64, unique=False, blank=False, null=False)
    page_type = models.CharField(max_length=50, default='POST')
    create_date = models.DateField(("Date"), default=datetime.date.today)
    contact = models.ForeignKey(UserProfile)
    contact2 = models.ForeignKey(UserProfile, related_name='+', blank=True, null=True)
    contact3 = models.ForeignKey(UserProfile, related_name='+', blank=True, null=True)
    contact4 = models.ForeignKey(UserProfile, related_name='+', blank=True, null=True)

    def __unicode__ (self):
        return u'%s %s %s' % (self.client, self.job_number, self.job_name)

    class Admin: 
         pass

    class Meta:
        permissions = (
            ('view_postpage', 'View postpage'),
        )
```

I think the override of the "clean" method in the forms code needs to be reconfigured based on the return value of the model. I'm just not sure how.

Comment: `models.DateField(("Date"), default=datetime.date.today)` - what's going on with `("Date")`?

Comment: I've always thought that's the proper syntax for the DateField. 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2029295/django-datefield-default-options

Comment: That question you linked is using `_("Date")` which means, in plain terms "mark the word _Date_ as translatable" - see the documentation on [translation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/i18n/translation/) to find out where the `_` comes from. You simply have `("Date")` which is the same as just writing `"Date"`.

Comment: interesting... I didn't notice the discrepancy. I'm using it in other models as well. Thanks for the link to appropriate documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not a good approach, to do it: it tries to call `.upper` for every object in `cleaned_data`, and it can be `int`, `None` and any other type.

The solution is something like:

```
return dict((k, v.strip().upper()) for k, v in self.cleaned_data.iteritems() if isinstance(v, basestring))
```

But why do you need this? May be it's better to store strings as is and just *display* them uppercased?

Comment: Thanks for the input. I need it because the input value becomes part of a path that requires uppercase values. I can't control whether or not an operator becomes sloppy and inputs lowercase values but if I can convert those values on the fly, it makes life a bit easier. Thank you again.