# How to keep only date part in Django DateField

Tags: django

I have a DateField defined in a model class like below and I only want to use it as Date type with no time part at all. However, once I loaded data in YYYY-MM-DD format, it auto added 12:00:00 AM.

FromDate = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)

I tried the solution from [Django DateField default options](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2029295/django-datefield-default-options) like date = models.DateField(_("Date"), default=date.today) but syncdb got me

NameError: name '_' is not defined

Django version 1.2.1 and 1.4.2 both had same error.

Did I miss anything?

Many thanks.

Comment: Where did you notice that it auto added 12:00:00?  A `DateField` should only be returning you a Python `datetime.date` instance.

Comment: @AustinPhillips is correct. It will auto added 12:00:00 if your field is DateTimeField

Comment: What database are you using?

Comment: mysql 5.1.41-3ubuntu12

Comment: please add your code, so we can see if you're doing something wrong

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps your DB has the column already created as datetime?  This could happen if, for example, you first had a `DateTime` field in your model, then ran `syncdb`, and then changed your model to use `Date`.

If that's the case, try amending the your DB table, or drop it and rerun `syncdb`.

Comment: Yes I always dropped table and rerun syncdb to recreate it, but it did not help.