# AttributeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'NoneType' and 'NoneType'

Tags: python, python-3.x, django-models, django-templates

My models.py:

```
class Attendancename(models.Model):
    teacher_name = models.ForeignKey(Teachername)
    date = models.DateField('Date')
    intime = models.DateTimeField('IN-TIME')
    outtime = models.DateTimeField('OUT-TIME')

    def hours_calculate(self):
        tdelta = self.outtime - self.intime
        tdelta = float(tdelta)/3600
        return tdelta
    def __str__(self):
        return "%s" %self.teacher_name
```

I want my above function `'hours_calculate'` to calculate total working hours based on intime and outtime fields but I got above error when rendering template. However from python shell I'm able to get `'seconds'` attribute of date object e.g,

```
>>>s1=datetime.datetime(2015,5,30,9)
>>>s2=datetime.datetime(2015,5,30,12)
>>>s=s2-s1
>>>s.seconds/3600
>>>3
>>>t=Attendancename.objects.order_by('teacher_name')
>>>print(type(t.intime))
>>><Class 'int'>
```

But in above django models using above function I got above Error. I don't know what's going wrong. Please anybody suggest me the fix.

I've no idea how it shows `'intime'` as a `'int'` type field. I've declared both `'intime'` and `'outtime'` as DateTImeField. What should I do now?

Comment: a quick check would be to run this in an interactive console and try looking at the `type(intime)`. If you see a `<type 'NoneType'>`, then you might want to look at what the return value of `models.DateTimeField('IN-TIME')` is.

Comment: It shows me <class 'int'> but, it's totally surprising. As I've declared both `'intime'` and `'outtime'` as DateTImeField. What should I do now?

Comment: After looking at some django docs and a previous question, you may be missing a parameter for the `models.DateTimeField()` method. Check out this : http://stackoverflow.com/a/2030142/5066845

and this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2771701/5066845

I'm still a beginner with django, so please bear with me :)

Comment: `DateTimeField` is represented by a Python `datetime.datetime` object, but I see that all parameters are optional if you are not changing the defaults. Maybe I'm asking a dumb question, but what does the string `'IN-TIME'` do as input? Just looking at this: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/fields/#datetimefield

Comment: `'IN-TIme'` is a parameter which specifies the field name in django-admin user interface...