# How to I represent a float and date fields that are not null in django correctly

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models

I am using `python 3` and `django 1.11` got the following data in a `.sql` file:
How do I use `DecimalField` and `DateField` components to represent the fields correctly.
I was thinking of doing something like this:

e.g `per_diem = models.DecimalField(max_digits=12, decimal_places=2,null=False)`
``

```
CREATE TABLE employee_per_diem (
    employee_per_diem_id    serial primary key,
    employee_month_id       integer references employee_month not gs,
    travel_date             date not null,
    return_date             date not null,
    days_travelled          integer not null,
    per_diem                float default 0 not null,
    cash_paid               float default 0 not null,
    tax_amount              float default 0 not null,
    full_amount             float default 0 not null,

);
```

Am I adding the `null` correctly?

Comment: Yes if you don't want that field to enter null,  `null=False` will do the work for you. Also by default `null` attribute value is `False`  no need to specify

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from django.db import models


class EmployeeMonthModel(models.Model):
    # your respective fields
    month = models.CharField(max_length=20)


class Employee(models.Model):
    employee_per_diem_id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    employee_month = models.ForeignKey(EmployeeMonthModel)
    travel_date = models.DateField()
    return_date = models.DateField()
    days_travelled = models.IntegerField()
    per_diem = models.FloatField()
    cash_paid = models.FloatField()
    tax_amount = models.FloatField()
    full_amount = models.FloatField()
```

by default django use `null=False`,so you dont have to define it explicitly

Answer (score 0):

Refer Below for the details

For Decimal fields

> https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/fields/

Example:

For example, to store numbers up to 999 with a resolution of 2 decimal places, you’d use:

```
models.DecimalField(..., max_digits=5, decimal_places=2)
```

For the Date Fields, you can refer the below-existing StackOverflow answer

[Django DateField default options](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2029295/django-datefield-default-options/2029339)

Comment: I already referred from django documentation but I needed clarification on using null on both components. as in is it proper to add `null =False` as parameters in the fields.